# Error : " execute() is called on closed connection when trying to persist value with an Update sql statement" in java . Implementing Apis with jax-rs

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EcaK.png)I am  trying to persist a value in my table using an update sql statement but i got this error : "  execute() is called on closed connection" .. Someone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: all the DB have a lifetime after that they close automatically, so can you share your code here.

Comment: Maybe your SQL server is down!. Or Make sure that host name is right in your app environment.

Comment: How would you expect anyone to answer if you dont show a snippet of your code where the error occurs?

Comment: @CHAHISaad i've added the link of my code image .. when running it , it highlights the " Pm.executeUpdate();" code in red

Comment: @GyroGearless , i've added the link of my code image .. when running it , it highlights the " Pm.executeUpdate();" code in red

Comment: Have you initialised `con` somewhere? If so, it's not in your snippet (which would be more convienient to be implemented as text instead of an image).

Also, what happened between the initialising of `con` and the call of `executeUpdate()`? Do you maybe call `con.close()` or a subroutine that sends a request to your DB itself? Such things can interfere based on the DB config and your connection handling.